# How to set access to selected images at CEPH rbd pool?

Tags: ceph

I want to give access for a client to selected images on rbd pool.
How can i do it ?

For now i use

```
ceph auth get-or-create client.cdata1 mon 'profile rbd' osd 'profile rbd pool=data1'
```

This allow client "cdata1" to see and mount **all** images in pool "data1" I want to user cdata1 will have access to only selected images inside pool "data1", how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- first you have to create an rbd image , example:

```
rbd create rbd-image --size 1000000 --pool data1 --image-feature layering
rbd info data1/rbd-image
```

then you can use the  block_name_prefix

```
ceph auth get-or-create client.cdata1 mon 'profile rbd' osd 'allow rwx pool data1 object_prefix rbd_data.xxxxxxxxxx; allow rwx  pool data1 object_prefix rbd_header.xxxxxxxxxxx ;allow rx pool data1 object_prefix rbd_id.rbd-image' -o ceph.client.rbd-image.keyring
```